# Partition recovery

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, ext4

During a fresh installation, I accidentally formatted a disk containing datas.

I tried using [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the erased partition, but , it only detects the new one. 
With the deeper search mode, I got a list of partitions, but which are not the partition I am looking for, as it fills the entire disk. 
[image]

I also tried to use [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) to recover files but the result is not a huge amount of partial files (video, texts are often not complete), and there is no hierarchy at all anymore.

As there is nothing more than the partition table which have been written over the last one, I guess it must be possible to recover it quite entirely, just by rebuilding the root inode. 
So, could you tell me some ways to achieve that?

Comment: Did you do a normal format or low format. If you have done a low format it has deleted all the data not only the inode table

Comment: Did you install over the formatted partition? If so you'll have a very hard time recovering your data...

Comment: It is during a debian installation, I think it is a fast format.

Comment: @Big Cris: no, nothing have been written but the partition table.

Comment: Did testdisk allow you to search for any other partitions using its more advanced search?

Comment: yes, but I got a list of patition which is not the real one, as this one was filling the entire disk, and no partition on this list correspond to that. See the sreenshot I have added to the post.